# How do I make a scrollable list of months in Flutter (Calendar)?

Tags: flutter

I want to implement something like this in my Flutter app-

[image]

I tried using [table_calendar](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar) but wasn't able to set the initial month for each `TableCalendar` in my `ListView.builder` widget which contains the 12 months. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also looking for the above

Comment: Nope :( @Bollie

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pub [Link](https://pub.dev/packages/scrolling_years_calendar). A customizable calendar widget to easily scroll through the years